# Why am I sometimes getting a 404 error when I try to update a page with Elementor?

Tags: plugins, page-template, errors, security, 404-error

When updating a page with Elementor, we're occasionally receiving a 404 error.

Most of the time we can update the page just fine, but when we try to add a `<script>` tag or a button with a custom font color it gives us a 404 Server Error.

What could be causing the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The exact cause of a 404 error can vary, but if you're receiving it when updating Elementor or making any other kind of call to `admin-ajax.php` and it only happens when performing very specific actions, then there's a good chance that it's security related.

I've had this error happen several times across several completely different WordPress sites. It doesn't seem to be specifically related to Elementor, though in my experience it happens more frequently with Elementor.

In every case that I've had so far, the cause was that the network request was being blocked by a security rule (false positive).

One time it was due to WordFence, so I used their [Learning Mode](https://www.wordfence.com/help/firewall/learning-mode/) feature to whitelist the action.

Another time it was triggered by [Namecheap's mod_security rules](https://www.namecheap.com/support/knowledgebase/article.aspx/9542/22/what-is-modsecurity-and-why-do-we-need-it), so I [contacted their support](https://www.namecheap.com/support/live-chat/general.aspx) and had them whitelist it.

Answer (score 1):

I resolve this disabling "Modsecurity" in Cpanel.
[image: Modsecurity disable]

Comment: Thanks for answering Daniel, please try and include a bit of an explanation as to what your actions do and why they address the problem.